# how do I solve flutter unmounted state?

Tags: flutter, widget, state, dispose

This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active. This error is happening only upon closing the file after using open file to open the file. If I don't click open file on the snackbar, the issue doesn't appear.

I have tried using mounted checks and super.dispose() but they haven't solved the issue.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_saver/file_saver.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

import '../utils/constants_image.dart';

class DownloadWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String downloadUrl;
  final String fileName;

  const DownloadWidget({required this.downloadUrl, required this.fileName});

  @override
  _DownloadWidgetState createState() => _DownloadWidgetState();
}

class _DownloadWidgetState extends State<DownloadWidget> {
  String downloadStatus = '';
  String filePath = '';
  double downloadProgress = 0.0;
  bool isDownloadComplete = false;

  Future<void> _downloadFile() async {
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      downloadStatus = 'Downloading...';
    });

    final client = HttpClient();
    final request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(widget.downloadUrl));
    final response = await request.close();
    final totalBytes = response.contentLength;
    var receivedBytes = 0;

    final bytes = <int>[];
    await for (var chunk in response) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      bytes.addAll(chunk);
      receivedBytes += chunk.length;
      setState(() {
        downloadProgress = receivedBytes / totalBytes;
      });
    }

    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    filePath = '${directory.path}/${widget.fileName}';
    final file = File(filePath);
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    await FileSaver.instance.saveFile(
      name: widget.fileName,
      mimeType: MimeType.mp3,
      filePath: filePath,
      file: file,
    );

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      downloadStatus = 'Download complete!';
      isDownloadComplete = true;
    });

    print('Directory: ${directory.path}');
    print('File path: $filePath');

    _showSnackBar();
  }

  void _openFile(String filePath) async {
    final file = File(filePath);

    if (file.existsSync()) {
      if (!mounted) return;

      await OpenFile.open(file.path);
    } else {
      print('File does not exist: $filePath');
    }
  }

  void _showSnackBar() {
    if (!mounted) return;

    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('Download complete!'),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'Open File',
        onPressed: () {
          _openFile(filePath);
        },
      ),
    );

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 48,
                  height: 48,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    value: isDownloadComplete ? 1.0 : downloadProgress,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    isDownloadComplete ? checkmarkIcon : downloadIcon,
                    width: 24,
                    height: 24,
                  ),
                  onPressed: isDownloadComplete ? null : _downloadFile,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post the error log here?